# Pointer initialization doubt

Tags: linux, pointers, gcc, malloc

We could initialize a character pointer like this in C.

`char *c="test";`

Where c points to the first character(t).

But when I gave code like below. It gives segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{

    int *i=0;
    printf("%d",*i);
}
```

Also when I give

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int *i;
    i=(int *)malloc(2);
    *i=0;
    printf("%d",*i);
}
```

It worked(gave output 0).

When I gave `malloc(0)`, it worked(gave output 0).

Please tell what is happening

Comment: Stop casting malloc, at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is seg faulting because you are trying to de-reference a null pointer which you have created with the line:

```
int *i=0;
```

You can't de-reference a pointer that doesn't point to anything and expect good things to happen. =)

The second code segment works because you have actually assigned memory to your pointer using malloc which you may de-reference.  I would think it's possible for you to get values other than zero depending on the memory adjacent to the address you're allocated with malloc.  I say this because typically an int is 4 bytes and you've only assigned 2.  When de-referencing the int pointer, it should return the value as an int based on the 4 bytes pointed to.  In your case, the first 2 bytes being what you received from the malloc and the adjacent 2 bytes being whatever is there which could be anything and whatever it is will be treated as if it was an int.  You could get strange behavior like this and you should malloc the size of memory needed for the type you are trying to use/point at.
(i.e.  `int *i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));` )

Once you have the pointer pointing at memory that is of the correct size, you can then set the values as such:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *i = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *i = 25;
    printf("i = %d\n",*i);

    *i = 12;
    printf("i = %d\n",*i);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit based on comment:**

A pointer points to memory, not to values.  When initializing `char *ptr="test";` You're not assigning the value of "test", you're assigning the memory address of where the compiler is placing "test" which is placed in your processes data segment and is read only.  It you tried to modify the string "test", you program would likely seg-fault.  What you need to realize about a char * is that it points at a single (i.e. the first) character in the string.  When you de-reference the char *, you will see 1 character and one character only.  C uses null terminated strings, and notice that you do not de-reference ptr when calling printf, you pass it the pointer itself and that points at just the first character.  How this is displayed depends on the format passed to printf.  When printf is passed the '%c' format, it will print the single character ptr points at, if you pass the format '%p' it will print the address that ptr points.  To get the entire string, you pass '%s' as the format.  What this makes printf do is to start at the pointer you passed in and read each successive byte until a null is reached.  Below is some code that demonstrates these.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize to data segement/read only string
    char *ptr = "test";
    printf("ptr points at     = %p\n", ptr);   // Prints the address ptr points to
    printf("ptr dereferenced  = %c\n", *ptr);  // Prints the value at address ptr
    printf("ptr value         = %s\n", ptr);   // Prints the string of chars pointed to by ptr

    // Uncomment this to see bad behavior!
    // ptr[1] = 'E'; // SEG FAULT -> Attempting to modify read-only memory

    printf("--------------------\n");

    // Use memory you have allocated explicitly and can modify
    ptr = malloc(10);
    strncpy(ptr, "foo", 10);
    printf("ptr now points at = %p\n", ptr);   // Prints the address ptr points to
    printf("ptr dereferenced  = %c\n", *ptr);  // Prints the value at address ptr
    printf("ptr value         = %s\n", ptr);   // Prints the string of chars pointed to by ptr

    ptr[1] = 'F';  // Change the second char in string to F
    printf("ptr value (mod)   = %s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialization of character pointer is different from integer pointer? Since we could initialize it like `char *ptr="test"`

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I have one question remaining. Then why the same concept not works with `int *i=12;`. This gives segmentation fault on printing values

Comment: It doesn't work because you're assigning a *value* (that being 12) to a pointer that doesn't have memory associated with it to store said value.  The C compiler puts literal char strings (i.e. "test") in the process data memory area as part of the language and assigns char *x the address of that location.  So there, you are assigning a pointer to a pointer *pointing* at "test", not a pointer to a *value* of "test".  Clear as mud right? :)